# History of Embedded Software

Tags: embedded

As far as I understand it, embedded software is just software (that runs on a general purpose CPU) that has little if any user input or configuration.  Embedded software powers IP routers, cars, computer mice, etc.

My question is:
When (roughly) was the historical moment when embedded software was first considered cost-effective for some applications (rather than an equal technical solution not involving embedded software)?  Which applications and why?

Detail: Obviously there is a tradeoff between the cost of a CPU fast enough to perform X in software versus the cost of designing hardware that performs X.

Comment: maybe try programmers stackexchange

Comment: I'd say the answer is tied to the introduction of the microprocessor, i.e. the mid 1970s.  Microprocessors were not developed & manufactured for microcomputers.  They were intended for replacing hardwired logic and for adding more sophisticated capabilities to military, industrial and medical equipment, i.e. devices that were not as cost-sensitive like consumer gear.  Eventually these uPs trickled down to commercial gear.  I purchased a VDT, for $500 in 1985 that had an embedded Z80 uP for an S100 bus uC.  The 1980s also saw a boom in digital watches, fueled by cheap uPs and LCDs.

Answer (score 3):

Embedded systems date from the Apollo moon landings.  Specifically the [Apollo Guidance Computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer) (AGC) - widely held to be one of the first examples of embedded systems.

Commercially in the early 1970's early microprocessors were being employed in products, famously the 4-bit [Intel 4004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004) used in the Busicom 141-PF.  Bill Gates and Paul Allen saw the potential for embedded microprocessors early with their pre-Microsoft endeavour the [Traf-O-Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traf-O-Data) traffic survey counter.

So I would suggest around 1971/72 at the introduction of the Intel 4004 and the more powerful 8-bit 8008.  Note that unlike the more powerful still Intel 8080 which inspired the first home-brew microcomputers and the MITS Altair, the 4004 and 8008 were barely suitable for use a general purpose "computer" as such, and therefore embedded computing systems pre-date general purpose microcomputers.

I would dispute your characterisation of what an embedded system is; if you were asking that question [here's my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425729/what-is-an-embedded-system-can-mobile-be-considered-as-an-embedded-product/11478877#11478877) to a similar question.